# How do I have a clickable Url as part of modal pop up output

Tags: html, jquery, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I am using modal popup with fullcalendar jquery plugin to display my event details on my ASP.NET mvc application and  I get my json events from the database. In the event details in the popup, I display the details using  jquery.text() methods; I have a url as part of the event data details, how do i make this url clickable to open in another tab in the modal pop up.

```
<h2>Organiser</h2>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='~/Content/Site.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='~/Content/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/list/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/list/main.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
                contentHeight: 820,
                weekends: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listMonth'
                },
                defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                eventClick: function (arg) {
                    $('#modalBody > #title').text(arg.event.title);
                    $('#modalSchool').text(arg.event.extendedProps.school);
                    $('#modalYear').text(arg.event.extendedProps.year);
                    $('#modalStaffs').text(arg.event.extendedProps.staffs);
                    $('#modalDescription').text(arg.event.extendedProps.description);
                    $('#modalWhen').text(arg.event.start);
                    $('#modalEnd').text(arg.event.end);
                    $('#modalRecord').text(arg.event.extendedProps.recordID);
                    $('#modalUrl').text(arg.event.extendedProps.url);
                    $('#calendarModal').modal();

                    //var $link = $('div#modalUrl');

                    //$('.modalUrl').click(function () {
                    //    window.open($link)
                    //});
                },

                events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) //function to run whenever the calendar needs events
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
                        data: { start: fetchInfo.startStr, end: fetchInfo.endStr }, 
                        success: function (data) {
                            var events = [];



                             $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                                 events.push({
                                     title: v.School,
                                     start: moment(v.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                                     end: moment(v.EndTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                                     color: v.Color,
                                     backgroundColor: v.Background,
                                     allDay: v.FullDay,
                                     
                                     extendedProps: {

                                        
                                         description: v.EventType,
                                         staffs: v.Staffs,
                                         recordID: v.Record,
                                         url: v.URL
                                         
                                     }



                                });
                            });

                            successCallback(events); //pass the events back to fullCalendar
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert('fetching events failed');
                            console.log(error);
                            failureCallback(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 1120px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }

        .fc-daygrid-event {
            white-space: normal !important;
            align-items: normal !important;
        }

        .fc .fc-toolbar-title {
            font-size: 1.3em !important;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .fc .fc-button {
            font-size: 0.8em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id='calendar' style="margin-top: 20px; "></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight: 700;">Event Details</h4>

                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">


                    <div id="modalDescription" style="margin-top:2px;"> <h4> At </h4></div>

                    <div id="modalSchool" style="margin-top:2px;"></div>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">On:</h4>
                    <div id="modalWhen" style="margin-top:2px; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden; max-width: 128pt;"></div>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">To</h4>
                    <div id="modalEnd" style="margin-top:2px; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden; max-width: 128pt;"></div>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Staff Members Booked:</h4>
                    <div id="modalStaffs" style="margin-top:2px;"></div>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" style=" width: 20%; float: left;">Record ID:</h4>
                    <div id="modalRecord" style="margin-top:2px;"></div>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Url</h4>
                    <div id="modalUrl" style="margin-top:2px;"></div>








                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have to unsuccessfully wrap the  in ahref tag, also unsuccessfully tried to use onclick.

Comment: Write the URL into the `href` property of an `<a href` element

Comment: The Url are dynamically gotten from the database, can you kindly show me how to write into the href property. I have tried calling the #modalUrl in the href property and it does not work correctly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "calling the modalUrl in the href property". But anyway it could just be something like `$('#modalUrl').html("<a href='" + arg.event.extendedProps.url + "'>" + arg.event.extendedProps.url + "</a>");` . See http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the URL into the `href` property of an `<a href` element, so it forms a hyperlink.

It could be something simple like:

```
$('#modalUrl').html("<a href='" + arg.event.extendedProps.url + "'>" + arg.event.extendedProps.url + "</a>");
```